# Justify property ignored for box-pack (-moz-box-pack) in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

The `justify` property for `-moz-box-pack` (or `box-pack`) seems to get ignored in Firefox.

[Live example](http://www.tekiki.com/itunes-store/apps/free-apps/all) from our site. The numbers in each row should get right-aligned, which they are in Chrome.

Any clues?

**HTML & CSS:**

```
<a class="category_box box_sizing" href="/itunes-store/apps/free-apps/category/all-apps?itunes-store-id=888-36" itunes_id="888-36" path="/36/888-36">
            <div class="name">All Apps</div> <div class="num_apps">43</div>
        </a>


.page_list .list a {
    color: #5C5C5C;
}
.page_list .category_box {
    -moz-box-pack: justify;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    display: -moz-box;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.box_sizing {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
    color: #5E87B0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a rendering bug to me. It seems to be supported.

Comment: could you post this as an answer please?

Answer (score 1):

use the following css rule:

```
.category_box .name {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

that should produce the result your looking for.

Check flexbox layout mode information, this should help you build what you want :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

http://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/

hope it helps